# Store json response in a variable in php

Tags: php

I am trying to send json request and store the response in a variable using php using the below code

```
 $hmaps_request = "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy&searchtext=3891 Delwood Drive, Powell, OH, United States";
 $json = file_get_contents($hmaps_request);
 $details = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

I could not get anyerrors as well as any response. But if i paste the url in browser i could get json response.

Comment: Please don't post someone's address in the question and your api tokens...

Comment: did you tried printing `$details` ? `$details['Response']['MetaInfo']`

Comment: Maybe wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Detects Your Problem

If you read the `$http_response_header` array (generated by [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) call), you'd find out that you got a "400 Bad Request" response and thus got nothing. So something must have gone wrong with your URL.

After a brief inspection, I think perhaps its your `"searchtext"` parameter that's blocking you. For starter, valid URL query don't usually have spaces in it. Probably why the API server says that you're a "Bad Request".

Normally, you need to properly escape the URL query string to have a proper URL. Modern browsers are very good at translating it for you seamlessly and automatically so you might not have this problem by using the URL directly in browsers.

### Solution

Let's put this theory to a test. We'll use [http_build_query()](http://php.net/http_build_query) to escape your query query parameters:

*(For privacy reason, the parameters are modified. Please substitute the query variables)*

```php
$query = http_build_query([
  'app_id' => 'your-app-id',
  'app_code' => 'your-app-code',
  'searchtext' => '123 Some Address',
]);
$url = 'https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?' . $query;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);

var_dump($details);
```

I seem to get proper decoded response now. Try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your request URL change the request URL

---

From

```
$hmaps_request = "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=NT2iR8TD1kAeCxERIow8&app_code=-r9pZGDuz6G5NWToLaCSUQ&searchtext=3891 Delwood Drive, Powell, OH, United States";
```

To

```
 $hmaps_request = "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=NT2iR8TD1kAeCxERIow8&app_code=-r9pZGDuz6G5NWToLaCSUQ&searchtext=3891+Delwood+Drive+Powell+OH+United+States";
```

Here is the full code

```
 $hmaps_request = "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=NT2iR8TD1kAeCxERIow8&app_code=-r9pZGDuz6G5NWToLaCSUQ&searchtext=3891+Delwood+Drive+Powell+OH+United+States";
 $json = file_get_contents($hmaps_request);
 $details = json_decode($json, TRUE);
 print_r($details);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error in your request URL. Please check below code.

```
$url = "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=NT2iR8TD1kAeCxERIow8&app_code=-r9pZGDuz6G5NWToLaCSUQ&searchtext=3891 Delwood Drive, Powell, OH, United States";
$url = str_replace(" ","%20",$url);
$json = @file_get_contents($url);
$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);
print_r($details);
```